# Wordpress Hacked 5.5 admin-ajax.php

Tags: admin, hacked

I am using the latest version (5.5) of WordPress themes and plugins. I also have 2 custom-written add-ons. I tried all the protection methods I know of.

- `wp-config.php` and wp-admin url and admin nick changed
- `.htaccess` disable `xmlrpc.php` and `wp-config.php`
- Installed Wordfence + 2FA login
- Password reset blocked
- MYSQL name and password is good.

I got hacked.

https://prnt.sc/u13mku see photo

`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and `wp-login.php`

Can you give me another idea for wp protection?

Hacker has tried this:

`?action=lostpassword` (a lot of and he login my wp-admin)
`wp-admin/admin-post.php?page=wysija_campaigns&action=themes` (I don’t use wysija)
`wp-login.php`

How can I close requests from outside to `admin-ajax.php`, `wp-login.php`, `wp-load.php`, etc.?

Comment: Stay calm. Read WordPress's [FAQ My site was hacked](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/) documentation.

Comment: Your site was not hacked, someone attempted to run an exploit and it failed, it was successfully blocked.

Comment: Yes attempted and another site hacked, i am installed new i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to access the login page happen all the time. Not a big deal....assuming that you have proper protections. Like:

- Not having a user named 'admin'
- Not allowing enumeration of user names (so user names aren't discoverable)
- Using strong passwords on all accounts, especially admin-level
- Using strong passwords on hosting, FTP, database, etc
- Disabling access to xmlrpc.prg (a common hack entry point)
- Being careful with user-uploaded files (if you let users create entries)
- General AV protection on your local computer (and good password policies)

I manage a lot of WP sites, and I don't worry about invalid login attempts, because I follow the above rules. I also have some security settings I apply by default (via a plugin that I wrote) to add to the htaccess file.

If a site does get hacked, then I follow a carefully evolved process of cleaning up the site. Lots of googles/bings/ducks on cleaning up a hacked WP site. My process is here https://www.securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ - there are many others.

Comment: Thanks your comment, As you already said, I did everything. But getting hacked.( can you help me. How i can block admin ajax

Comment: From the info you provided, your site has **not** been hacked. There are attempts to do logins/etc all the time on just about any site. If there is no indication of hacked files (code added), then you are OK. **Any** site, even a fresh install, will get attempt such as you have noticed. That doesn't mean they are hacked.